# cannot access mutable array in singleton

Tags: objective-c

singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CrestronControllerValues : NSObject {
NSString* ipAddress;
NSString* portNumber;
NSString* phoneAddress;
NSString* cameleonVersion;
NSString* systemName;
NSString* iPID;
NSString* systemFeedBackName;
NSString* dJoinConnectedFB;
NSString* dJoinLow;
NSString* dJoinHigh;
NSString* aJoinLow;
NSString* aJoinHigh;
NSString* sJoinLow;
NSString* sJoinHigh;
NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence;
NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat;
NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* ipAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* portNumber;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* phoneAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* cameleonVersion;

@property (nonatomic, retain)     NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence;

@property (nonatomic, retain)     NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat;

@property (nonatomic, retain)     NSMutableArray *currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* systemName;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* iPID;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* systemFeedBackName;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* dJoinConnectedFB;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* dJoinLow;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* dJoinHigh;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* aJoinLow;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* aJoinHigh;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* sJoinLow;

@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSString* sJoinHigh;

+ (id)sharedManager;
    @end
```

i have my singleton.m:

```
        static CrestronControllerValues *sharedMyManager= nil;

    @implementation CrestronControllerValues
    @synthesize ipAddress, portNumber ,systemName, iPID, systemFeedBackName, dJoinConnectedFB, dJoinLow, dJoinHigh, aJoinLow, aJoinHigh, sJoinLow, sJoinHigh, cameleonVersion, currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat, currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence, currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat, phoneAddress;


    +(CrestronControllerValues*)sharedManager
{
        @synchronized(self) {
    if(!sharedMyManager) {
        sharedMyManager = [CrestronControllerValues alloc];
        sharedMyManager = [sharedMyManager init];

    }
}
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        NSAssert(sharedMyManager == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        sharedMyManager = [super alloc];
        return sharedMyManager;
    }

    return nil;
}

    -(id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {
            // initialize stuff here
        self.ipAddress = @"10.8.40.64";
self.portNumber = 41794;
self.systemName = @"";
self.iPID = 3;
self.cameleonVersion = nil;
self.currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];  
self.currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];
self.currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];
self.phoneAddress = nil;
self.systemFeedBackName = @"";
self.dJoinConnectedFB = 5000;
self.dJoinLow = 1;
self.dJoinHigh = 1000;
self.aJoinLow = 1;
self.aJoinHigh = 1000;
self.sJoinLow = 1;
self.sJoinHigh = 1000;

        }
        return self; 
    }
        return self; 
    }

    -(void)setPhoneAddress:(NSString *)phoneaddress
    {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (phoneAddress != phoneaddress) 
            {
                [phoneAddress release];
                phoneAddress = [phoneaddress retain];
            }
        }
    }
    -(NSString*)getPhoneAddress
    {
        return phoneAddress;
    }
    -(void)setCurrentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat:(NSMutableArray *)entries
    {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat != entries) 
            {
                [currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat release];
                currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat = [entries retain];
            }
        }
    }
    -(NSMutableArray*)getCurrentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat
    {
        return currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat;
    }
    -(void)setCurrentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence:(NSMutableArray *)entries
    {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence != entries) 
            {
                [currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence release];
                currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence = [entries retain];
            }
        }
    }
    -(NSMutableArray*)getCurrentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence
    {
        return currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence;
    }
    -(void)setCurrentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat:(NSMutableArray *)entries
    {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat != entries) 
            {
                [currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat release];
                currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat = [entries retain];
            }
        }
    }
    -(NSMutableArray*)getCurrentPhonebookEntriesVideoChatLocal
    {
        return currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat;
    }
    -(void)setCameleonVersion:(NSString *)cameleonversion
    {
        cameleonVersion = cameleonversion;
    }
    -(NSString*)getCameleonVersion
    {
        return cameleonVersion;
    }
    -(void)setIPaddress:(NSString *)ipaddress
    {
        ipAddress = ipaddress;
    }
    -(NSString*)getIPaddress
    {
        return ipAddress;
    }
    -(void)setPortNumber:(NSString *)portnumber
    {
        portNumber = portnumber;
    }
    -(NSString*)getPortNumber
    {
        return portNumber;
    }
    -(void)setSystemName:(NSString *)systemname
    {
        systemName = systemname;
    }
    -(NSString*)getSystemName
    {
        return systemName;
    }

    -(void)setIPID:(NSString *)ipid 
    {
        iPID=ipid;
    }
    -(NSString*)getIpid
    {
        return iPID;
    }

    -(void)setSystemFeedBackName:(NSString *)systemfeedbackname
    {
        systemFeedBackName=systemfeedbackname;
    }
    -(NSString*)getSystemFeedBackName
    {
        return systemFeedBackName;
    }

    -(void)setDJoinConnectedFB:(NSString *)djoinconnectedfb
    {
        dJoinConnectedFB = djoinconnectedfb;
    }
    -(NSString*)getDJoinConnectedFB
    {
        return dJoinConnectedFB;
    }

    -(void)setDJoinLow:(NSString *)djoinlow
    {
        dJoinLow=djoinlow;
    }
    -(NSString*)getDJoinLow
    {
        return dJoinLow;
    }

    -(void)setDJoinHigh:(NSString *)djoinhigh
    {
        dJoinHigh = djoinhigh;
    }
    -(NSString*)getDJoinHigh
    {
        return dJoinHigh;
    }

    -(void)setAJoinLow:(NSString *)ajoinlow
    {
        aJoinLow = ajoinlow;
    }
    -(NSString*)getAJoinLow
    {
        return aJoinLow;
    }

    -(void)setAJoinHigh:(NSString *)ajoinhigh
    {
        aJoinHigh = ajoinhigh;
    }
    -(NSString*)getAJoinHigh
    {
        return aJoinHigh;
    }

    -(void)setSJoinLow:(NSString *)sjoinlow
    {
        sJoinLow = sjoinlow;
    }
    -(NSString*)getSJoinLow
    {
        return sJoinLow;
    }

    -(void)setSJoinHigh:(NSString *)sjoinhigh
    {
        sJoinHigh = sjoinhigh;
    }
    -(NSString*)getSJoinHigh
    {
        return sJoinHigh;
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [self.ipAddress release];
        [self.iPID release];
        [self.portNumber release];
        [self.currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat release];
        [self.currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence release];
        [self.currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat release];
        [self.aJoinHigh release];
        [self.aJoinLow release];
        [self.cameleonVersion release];
        [self.sJoinHigh release];
        [self.sJoinLow release];
        [self.dJoinHigh release];
        [self.dJoinLow release];
        [self.dJoinConnectedFB release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

and then i use it in 3 classes total
in one i set values:
if i read values from the CCV (sharedobject) i get the correct values.  but this is in the same class as they are set from

```
CCV = [CrestronControllerValues sharedManager];
CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat = currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat;
```

and another i read the values:
(these show/read as nil)

```
switch (viewOptions) {
    case 1:
        [self setTableArray:CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self setTableArray:CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat];
        break;
    case 3:
        [self setTableArray:CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesTelepresence];
        break;
    case 4:
        [self setTableArray:CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat];
        break;
    default:
        [self setTableArray:CCV.currentPhonebookEntriesVideoChat];
        break;
}
```

but besides the class that i actually set the values in i do not get the filled array when i access it from another class
i have done NSLOG(@"%@", CCV) and from what i can see all three classes have the same pointer so the shared instance seems to be working

Comment: i have tried it with and without the shareinstance. infront of my vars that im intializing, as well as overiding the setters

Comment: If you don't get the filled array, what DO you get? Is it an empty array? Can you also show your .h file where you declare the properties?

Comment: correct i get an empty or null array (add .h file)

Comment: Is it fair to ask why you're using such an obscure and complex pattern to implement a singleton?

Comment: ive tried multiple patterns, give me a simpler one to try and i will.  sometimes i get lost with the different ways i have tried.  but still i dont get why the nsstrings work but not the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so in the end all i can do is apologize.  none of you had the code that you would have needed to see what was going on.
here is the array being saved (aboved was abridged (bad idea))

```
            if ([phonebookEntriesAudioChat count] >=8) {                

                [CCV setCurrentPhonebookEntriesAudioChat:phonebookEntriesAudioChat];
                [phonebookEntriesAudioChat removeAllObjects];

            }
```

basically i was tring to add an item to the array from a socket return.  getting one address up to 8 for each return/message.  so i populated a temporary array (phonebookEntriesAudioChat) and added one to it for each message and once it got to 8 saved it to my singleton (CCV).  but some how (and im still trying to figure this out) it would get to 8, be saved, temporary array cleared, then resaved the array (an empty one) to the singleton.

thanks for all the help and direction, i know i dont get points for my own answer if one of you wants some easy points just re answer with a simliar description as this and ill give u the check.  otherwise im just going to vote up ur comments and mark this as the answer in a day or two.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplier singleton pattern, less code is more:

```
@implementation MySingleton
static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            _sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedMySingleton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sharedMyManager` has not been set at the time you are initializing the ivars.

In a init it is best practice to set the ivars directly, that is do not use setters such as created by `@synthesize`, the class is not completely established so calling methods on it is not a great idea.

A singleton is just a class like any other class with one exception, there is only one.  Also all the extra methods to guarantee a singleton are really just noise that is best not present--but that is a matter of taste.

Comment: not sure the direction you want me to take.  i had a bunch of getters and setters but removed them after further investigations (however the original tutorial, and others i found show them making a property).  from my understanding of property's is that it auto creates getters and setters.  i have all my ivars being intialized in the init method?  if i dont synthesize i get errors when setting things to these vars.

Comment: By all means create `@properties` and use the setters/getters always--except in `init` and `dealloc` where it may be best to directly assign/release.  Use `@synthesize` to create the setters/getters if there is nothing special to do in them--the usual case.

Comment: i get that you shouldnt use a setter from an init.  but using a setter i thought would be [foo setbar:foobar] or even foo.bar = foobar but how am i using a setter when i just say bar=foobar.  i understand from the other answer that it should be self, and i can grasp that since those are setting the iVars but what was i using before that was using setters?

Comment: `sharedMyManager.ipAddress = @"10.8.40.64";` is using a setter if ipAddress is a property.  It is equivalent to `[sharedMyManager setIpAddress:@"10.8.40.64]`.

Comment: i really think the important part that im missing is how should my setter look?  and is self. correct for the ivars.  i had it that way at one point but then started thinking i should load up the sharedMyManager object with values.

Comment: For your setter just use `@property (non atomic, retain) ClassName *iVarName and then `@synthesize`.  If you want to be sure you never inadvertently do not use self use: `@synthesize iVarName = _iVarName`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
sharedMyManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
```

Rewrite it as:

```
id x = [super allocWithZone:NULL];
id y = [x init];
sharedMyManager = y;
```

When `init` is executed, the assignment to `sharedMyManager` hasn't been evaluated yet.  Thus, `sharedMyManager` is `nil` and all your assignments are no-ops in your `init` method.

In your `init` method, you should *always* refer to your instance variables through `self`;  either by directly assignment to them (which is a reference to self, really) or using the setter methods directly (i.e. `self.foo = 442;`).

(This is what @CocoaFu said, but clarified)

---

Looking at the code a little more closely, there are a ton of problems with it.

- `NSString` properties should be `copy`, not `retain`.
- you are leaking all of the `currentPhonebookEntries*` mutable arrays.
- Getter methods should not have the prefix `get*`
- there is no need to implement any of those getter/setter methods when using `@synthesize` (and you are actually creating two getter methods for each; one with and one without the `get` prefix).
- the `dealloc` method should either directly release the instance variables or it should set the properties to `nil`;  the `[self.ivar release]` is discouraged.

The code I showed above is merely illustrative.   If your `init` still assigns through `sharedMyManager`, you didn't fix the problem.

Comment: i made the changes per your posting but still having the same problem.  going to repost code and add some more.  but i have a side question.  you almost always see foo * bar = [[foo alloc]init].  for init statments, i understand your post and see what your saying but then why is this method of initialization so common (what am i missing)

Comment: i dont understand, other values work but not my arrays.  any other ideas?