# Singleton objects with mutable members

Tags: c++, static, singleton, mutable

EDIT: See GWW's answer, the problem was simply making an illicit copy with C::Instance().  And I was wrong, the error does not depend on mutable.

Are static methods incompatible with mutable methods?  Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
c.h:

class C 
{
    public:
        static C& Instance();
    private:
        C();

        mutable QMutex _mutex; 
};

c.cpp:

C& C::Instance() 
{
    static C instance;
    return instance; 
} 
C c = C::Instance();
```

Then the error I'm getting (gcc 4.2) is

> error: 'QMutex::QMutex(const QMutex&)' is private within this context
>
> synthesized method 'C::C(const C&)' first required here //at C::Instance()

If I remove the 'mutable' keyword this error goes away, but then of course I can't make the methods that lock/unlock _mutex const.  Writing my own copy ctor doesn't change anything. Anyone know how to solve this?  NB this looks similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728731/cannot-access-mutable-array-in-singleton) but that's objective-C and there was just too much code in there that didn't seem relevant to the question.

EDIT: Just realized that the problem, obviously, is that QMutex's copy ctor is private.  But I don't understand why 'mutable' should make a difference here, i.e. why it induces a copy.

Comment: `C c = C::Instance();` will copy the instance? Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @GWW Oh LOL you are right! *blush*

Comment: So the question boils down to: how does `mutable` affect the public/private nature of the compiler generated copy constructor?

Comment: @Mark Ok I double-checked and actually I do get the same error, just hadn't seen it the first time.  Deleting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to copy your singleton and it fails because you have declared a copy constructor private. It has absolutely nothing to do with mutable members.

Comment: `C & c = C::Instance();` will probably fix that